# Enable/disable radio button based on another

Tags: javascript

i have radio buttons actualdays_month,only working days. 
my requirement is if i press one rdb then another rdb have to disable. Here both id and name are same for all radio buttons

```
<label><input type="radio" name="salarycalenderyears" value="ActualDays_Month" checked="checked" id="salarycalenderyears" title="">Actual Days / Month</label><br>
```

Only Working Days
Only Working Days + WH
Only Working Days + WH + PH

Comment: What did you try? What are the specific problems you ran into?

Comment: You dont need to disable them. If you have a group of radio buttons the default behaviour is, if you select one then it deselects the others.

Comment: here in my code i have name and id same...i know how to enable or disable code based on id or name..but the problem is as im having name and id as same i am unable to know how to enable/disable one radio button if another is checked

Comment: ya i know if one is selected another one will be deselected..i have two groups of radio buttons..for ex one radio group containinng rdb as animals,birds,fruits..and another radio groups with animal names,fruit names....when i select animal rdb thn animal groub rdb have to be enabled...fruits have to be disabled

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do http://jsfiddle.net/beradrian/cAdmu/?

```
function onChange() {
   $("[name='type']").each(function() {
       var disabled = !this.checked;
       $("[name='" + this.value + "']").each (function() {
           this.disabled = disabled;
       });
  });
}

onChange();
$("[name='type']").change(onChange);
```