# Disable radio button based on previous radio selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-selectors, radio-button

I need to enable radio options based on two previous selected radios,
I have already made a question on a [pervious topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740772/how-can-one-avoid-selecting-2-radio-buttons-with-the-same-value) and I tried unsuccessfully to adapt it to the new need, and I also tried using the answer to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816853/enable-disable-radio-button-based-on-another), but also unsuccessfully...

So here's some more details about what I need: I select one radio from each of two previous radio groups, so at the third group should be available (enabled) to pick only those two which correspond to the previous selection...

*First group*: de, en, es, ca (selected)

*Second group*: de, en (selected), es, ca

*Third group*: de (disabled), en (enabled), es (disabled), ca (enabled)

And here is the code I'm using:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name=lang_or]').click(function() {
    $('input[name=lang_tg]').prop('disabled', false);
    $('input[name=lang_tg][value=' + this.value).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Origin language</th>
    <th>Target language</th>
    <th>Language to index first</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="de">German</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="en">English</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="ca">Catalan</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="es">Spanish</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="fr">French</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="it">Italian</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="pt">Portugues</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="de">German</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="en">English</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="ca">Catalan</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="es">Spanish</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="fr">French</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="it">Italian</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="pt">Portugues</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label><input type="radio" name="language" value="de">German</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="language" value="en">English</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="language" value="ca">Catalan</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="language" value="es">Spanish</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="language" value="fr">French</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="language" value="it">Italian</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="language" value="pt">Portugues</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Well just from a click glance `$('input[name=lang_tg][value=' + this.value)` Is missing the end part of the selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed you *click listener* to `$('input[name^=lang_]').click(function() {` for it to *target* both the first and second group of radio buttons.

Now inside you click listener, you can check only *those* radio buttons that are *checked* in the first and second group of radio buttons:

```
$('input[name^=lang_]:checked').each(function() {
   $('input[name=language][value=' + $(this).val() + ']').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

See demo below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // initialize all to disabled
  $('input[name=language]').prop('disabled', true);

  // click listener for 1st and 2nd groups
  $('input[name^=lang_]').click(function() {
    // disable all first
    $('input[name=language]').prop('disabled', true);
    // enable currently selected radios
    $('input[name^=lang_]:checked').each(function() {
      $('input[name=language][value=' + $(this).val() + ']').prop('disabled', false);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Origin language</th>
    <th>Target language</th>
    <th>Language to index first</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="de">German</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="en">English</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="ca">Catalan</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="es">Spanish</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="fr">French</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="it">Italian</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="pt">Portugues</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="de">German</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="en">English</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="ca">Catalan</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="es">Spanish</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="fr">French</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="it">Italian</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="pt">Portugues</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label><input type="radio" name="language" value="de">German</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="language" value="en">English</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="language" value="ca">Catalan</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="language" value="es">Spanish</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="language" value="fr">French</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="language" value="it">Italian</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="language" value="pt">Portugues</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just added your function, because if I edit the previous one I lose the hability to disable the coincident radio button of the second group.

Answer (score 1):

You can get array of values of first two input groups and check each input from third group if its value is in array and disabled it if not.

```js
var i = $('input[name="language"]');
i.prop('disabled', true)

$("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
  var val = $('input[name=lang_or]:checked, input[name=lang_tg]:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).val()
  }).get()

  i.each(function() {
    $(this).prop('disabled', !val.includes($(this).val()))
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Origin language</th>
    <th>Target language</th>
    <th>Language to index first</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="de">German</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="en">English</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="ca">Catalan</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="es">Spanish</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="fr">French</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="it">Italian</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="pt">Portugues</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="de">German</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="en">English</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="ca">Catalan</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="es">Spanish</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="fr">French</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="it">Italian</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="pt">Portugues</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label><input type="radio" name="language" value="de">German</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="language" value="en">English</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="language" value="ca">Catalan</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="language" value="es">Spanish</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="language" value="fr">French</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="language" value="it">Italian</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="language" value="pt">Portugues</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

U said:

> I select one radio from each of two previous radio groups, so at the
>   third group should be available (enabled) to pick only those two which
>   correspond to the previous selection...

First Radio buttons are there for a single choice. 
So you can't check more then one language this way..

if you want to pick **only one**, than use radio..

I made some changes in your js too, take a look:
https://jsfiddle.net/eb7u4zu8/1/

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Origin language</th>
  <th>Target language</th>
  <th>Language to index first</th></tr>
<tr><td>
<label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="de">German</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="en">English</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="ca">Catalan</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="es">Spanish</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="fr">French</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="it">Italian</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="lang_or" value="pt">Portugues</label>
</td><td>
<label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="de">German</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="en">English</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="ca">Catalan</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="es">Spanish</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="fr">French</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="it">Italian</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="lang_tg" value="pt">Portugues</label>
</td><td class='thirdGroup'>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="de">German</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="en">English</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="ca">Catalan</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="es">Spanish</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="fr">French</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="it">Italian</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="pt">Portugues</label>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('input[name=language]').attr("disabled", true);

  $('input[name=lang_or]').change(function(){
    enableDisable($("input[name=lang_or]:checked").val(),   $("input[name=lang_tg]:checked").val());
  });

  $('input[name=lang_tg]').change(function(){
    enableDisable($("input[name=lang_or]:checked").val(),   $("input[name=lang_tg]:checked").val());
  });


});

function enableDisable(lang_or, lang_tg){
    if($('input[name=lang_or]').is(":checked") && $('input[name=lang_tg]').is(":checked")){
    $('input[name=language]').attr("disabled", true).prop('checked', false);

        $("input[name=language][value="+lang_or+"]").prop('checked', true).attr("disabled", false);
    $("input[name=language][value="+lang_tg+"]").prop('checked', true).attr("disabled", false);
  }else{
    $('input[name=language]').attr("disable", true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works also, but it is not so intuitive for the user, I changed the checkbox to radio to be able to select only one of the third group, and it gets automatically selected the language equal to the second group. And I also need to keep the function I mentioned at the previous thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740772/how-can-one-avoid-selecting-2-radio-buttons-with-the-same-value